# opengl - flash of light (like when shooting)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

I'm trying to create flash of light (like when someone is shooting). For e.g. (it's from real video, but i need something similar, much more simpler):

[image]

I need to do this using only OpenGL - can't model this one. It would be nice if it could be a little random. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: It's called a muzzle flash and you don't implement it with just lighting, you implement it primarily with a texture and blending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how good you want this to look, but you can fake it by using an alpha textured quads that are laid out in a cross, you can move the texture a little every frame in the direction of where the muzzle is pointing to make it look like as if it is moving.

It is simple and easy to implement and the flash should be a quick thing so the user will never know be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Since these flashes are *adding light*, [additive blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_Equations) is commonly used.

Comment: @Caesar: But you mean i just have to generate circo about 100 quads a little transparent and color them in a proper way?